# Tracking User with Google Ad Link

Tags: google-ads-api, spam-prevention

I'm not sure I've stated the title correctly, but I have what I think is an unusual issue. Not something I'm terribly worried about but curious.  If I'm tagging this inappropriately I apologize.

I have a google ad running and track clicks using Final URL.  So I track keywords, Ad_ID, Location, etc.  Looking at the database I noticed that I am getting a hit on my website from what appears to be one user fairly regularly (sometimes minutes apart - other times days - 3200 entries) for the last 2 years, at least to when I started tracking this way.  The entry shows the same keywords and the same location - which is local - a mobile device - but not an Ad_ID or a referring URL. I take the google info from the query string in the url so the query string would have to be the same every time.

I recently added a tracking cookie (long expiration) on the user end and this activity shows up with a different cookie value every time meaning either its either a different device or the device doesn't accept cookies. Each hit also starts a new session.

These hits do not show up as clicks on Google Ads so I'm not being charged, it also means that someone is not actually out there clicking on the ad.

I don't see where this is causing problems but am curious as to where this may be coming from.  I don't know if there is a way to stop it.

So nothing critical but ideas on what might be causing this would be appreciated.  I also get a ton of spam or bot hits on the site but that's a different issue.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have the IP you can exclude it, have you the ip?

Comment: I thought of that but my understanding is that the ip isn't that specific - could be just the isp and I don't necessarily want to block that - or am I wrong?

Comment: The ip is that specific... And if it is a bot it is really common that it always have the same ip

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into that then